# Is there a faster way to hatch eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm needing to find some way of hatching my eggs faster They're taking forever and I only have one incubator!

Comment: You *can* cycle faster.

Comment: @DeMize There is a speed limit

Comment: @Riley Cycling can be done in all Pokemon games including Pokemon GO.

Comment: @DeMize As I said if you go too fast it won't work. Pokemon GO is totally different from all the pokemon games

Comment: @Riley I am just saying that every Pokemon game has cycling in it. So in Pokemon GO, you can hatch eggs faster if you cycle in the real world.

Comment: @DeMize you can't cycle in Pokémon Pinball. :p

Comment: @Trollwut Or Pokemon Snap for that matter

Answer (score 10):

Egg hatching has an unconfirmed speed limit to prevent people shaking their phones in cars, but I find that biking is much more efficient than walking when it comes to hatching eggs.

Comment: Just like in the main series!

Comment: I've heard the speed limit is 20km/h, so that might be a decent point of reference to use.

Comment: @jackwise I've heard 20km/h and 30km/h. Not sure which one is correct.

Comment: Problem is, it's not very safe to use your phone and cycle. Having to constantly unlock your phone after a timeout or make sure a random button wasn't pressed, isn't ideal...

Comment: @Draken if you are on android, there are apps like "Stay Alive" that you can use to keep PoGo alive and tracking no matter what.

Comment: I read people saying in a forum that the limit is 14km/h. But I've tested driving around 20km/h and did count some distance on eggs, not accurate but enough to hatch some 5K eggs in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 7):

I actually found a pretty great way to hatch eggs. I know it works but I haven't confirmed the rate at which I can hatch them.

First I secured my iPhone to the ceiling fan. I have a brass knuckle phone case so I just tied the knot through the finger hole and duct taped it to the fan. Then I realized it wasn't registering, because I didn't have walking movements, so I lengthened the string so it would nearly touch the wall, and then I put a pillow on the wall. The phone hits the pillow harmlessly and then shakes when it hits to simulate walking.

You're all very welcome.

Comment: This seems horribly risky for your phone.

Comment: if you can tie a knot correctly, the only risk is somebody putting a brick in your pillow. its on the lowest setting it can't possibly fall

Comment: Best answer to any question I've read all day.

Comment: If your ceiling fan is on and better alternatives are unavailable, okay, but that is one of the least efficient ways of registering distance.  The minimum distance resolution of a typical phone's GPS is 10 meters (perhaps smaller internally).  The diameter of your phone's circular path must cross a GPS location boundary, and the app must take GPS readings when on opposite sides of the boundary.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to hatch eggs faster. The only thing you can do is use more than one incubator at one time to hatch multiple eggs at the same time.

The faster you go, obviously the more ground you cover in a shorter amount of time.

The speed limit is around 15MPH (24km/h), so going any faster than that will not count toward your progress.

Comment: 24km/hr is a fast, but not uncomfortable speed for me to cycle at. It is a bit slow for people on racing bikes; so cycling wouldn't help everyone. +1 for pointing out the speed cap.

Answer (score 3):

As you level up you gain new incubators. e.g. if you get level 6 you get an incubator with 3 uses before it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are ways.

I saw one persons use a drone. 
Someone else said strap it to a dog and play fetch. 
I tried to tape my phone to a string and to a ceiling fan (for length). Results are inconclusive.

I also tried straping my phone on a rumba auto vacuum. It moves slow and .1km is over 300 feet. I don't think I let it run long enough to show a result.

Get creative. How do you move your phone 15mph or less without walking but in a big enough distance to be tracked by gps?

Comment: I would not recommend the ceiling fan suggestion. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: the app also works like a pedometer, checking for "walking-like" movements, so simply moving the phone around to trigger the GPS may not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dog, you can buy them a small pouch, and stick your phone into the backpack - then play fetch. The phone picks up the running as actual steps, it's the fastest way without leaving your couch

Answer (score 1):

My eggs seem to hatch on the bus.  For best results, take the bus through a downtown area so you're not traveling too fast.  This is also a great way to get experience points from spinning lots of pokestops.

I've never gotten a good pokemon out of an egg, though.  Weird rare pokemon, yes.  Useful pokemon, no.

Comment: All first evolutions can be obtained except legendaries. It's random.